# Cant not get two if else statements to work? checking strings and numbers

Tags: javascript

I would like to run these two if else statement but I can not get them to work ? please help.

1. if input is a sting fail go back to beginning and ask again.

   ```
   function table(){
       var num = prompt("please enter any number");
       if (num <= 0 && typeof num != 'string') {
           alert("invalid number or Zero") ;
           table();
       } else {
           alert("ok") ;
       }
   }

   table();
   ```
2. if not correct text back to beginning and ask again.

   ```
   function text(){
       var txt = prompt("please enter rock or scissors or paper");
       if (txt != "rock" || "scissors" || "paper") {
           alert("failed") ;
           table();
       } else {
           alert("ok") ;
       }
   }

   text();
   ```

thank you.

Comment: 1. The return value of `prompt` is **always** a string. 2. Learn how logical operators work. `"scissors"` and `"paper"` will **always** be true, because you let them stand on their own, and don't compare them to `txt`.

Comment: @Siguza: The return value of `prompt` is *usually* a string. If the user cancels, it's `null` (which is not a string).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Alright, got me there. I should have said "never a number"...

Answer (score 3):

The `typeof` the result you get back from `prompt` will **always** be either `"string"` (the user clicked OK or pressed Enter) or `"object"` (the user clicked Cancel or pressed Esc), because `typeof null` is `"object"` and `prompt` returns what was typed, or `null` on cancel. So that's what's wrong with the first `if`.

If blanks are not acceptable, the simple check is `!`:

```
var num = prompt(...);
if (!num) {
    // User clicked Cancel or didn't type anything
}
```

...then use `+num` to convert `num` to a number, or use `parseInt(num, 10)` to do so if you want to ensure base 10 and ignore any text after the number (`parseInt("42foo", 10)` is `42` rather than `NaN`; `+"42foo"` is `NaN`).

The second `if`'s problem is that you have to repeat what you're testing and use `&&` rather than `||`:

```
if (txt != "rock" && txt != "scissors" && txt != "paper"){
```

"If txt is not rock and txt is not scissors and..."

A `switch` might be useful there:

```
switch (txt) {
    case "rock":
    case "scissors":
    case "paper":
        alert("ok") ;
        break;
    default:
        alert("failed") ;
        table();
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with following syntaxes:

```
var num = parseInt( prompt("please enter any number") );
if (num <= 0) {
  // ...
}
```

And the second case:

```
var txt = prompt("please enter rock or scissors or paper");
if (txt != "rock" && txt != "scissors" && txt !=  "paper") {
  // ...
}
```